# Grep user input to find number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a File which looks like this

```
example text [1234] [0] Part 2 /var/tmp/path
example text [1234] [0] Part 3 /var/tmp/path
example text [1234] [0] Some Text more text
example text [1235] [0] Part 4 /var/tmp/path
example text [1235] [0] Part 5 /var/tmp/path
example text [1236] [0] Part 6 /var/tmp/path
example text [1236] [0] other text foo bar
```

I have another text file where users can write the parts in.
So it can look like this:

```
Part 2
Part 4
Part 6
```

I need a grep or so the second file gets read and it searched for the numbers in the first bracket, and saves them into an variable

In the example I'd need to get the output

```
1234
1235
1236
```

And it should be in a variable to use it for further work

So far I tried it with

```
grep -F -f parts.txt search.log
```

But I don't know how to not get the line where Part 2, 4 and 6 are shown, but only the number within the first brackets

Comment: What have you done? Edit: question, and post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
myparts=$(grep -F -f parts.txt search.log | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)
```

parts.txt is the file that users write part numbers in.

grep returns the lines where part number matches.
awk uses `[` and `]` as delimiters to extract the first word between them

Comment: Add -F option to grep and try it

Comment: grep + awk is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if only a single grep statement can do that work but a small loop can.

```
cat file2 |while read line
do
   grep $line file1|awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/\[//g'|sed 's/\]//g' >> tempfile
done
```

Now the tempfile can be used further or instead of temp file you can put that in a variable by

```
abcd="$abcd (grep $line file1|awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/\[//g'|sed 's/\]//g')"
```